# What is a purely functional data structure that efficiently implements rendering to an image?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, data-structures, time-complexity

Images and pixel-rendering are one of the last things in Haskell I couldn't pick an efficient enough purely functional data structure for. For simplicity, lets talk about `1D` images, since those can easily extended to n-d images. I'm using unboxed vectors as the representation and their mutable view for rendering:

```
-- An 1D image is an unboxed vector of Pixels
type Position = Int
data Image    = Image { size :: Position, buffer :: UV.Vector Pixel }

-- A sprite is a recipe to draw something to an Image
newtype Sprite = Sprite (forall s .
    -> (Position -> Pixel -> ST s ()) -- setPixel
    -> ST s ())                       -- ST action that renders to Image

-- Things that can be rendered to screen provide a sprite
class Renderable a where
    getSprite a :: a -> Sprite

-- `render` applies all sprites, mutably, in sequence. `O(P)` (where P = pixels to draw)
render :: [Sprite] -> Image -> Image
render draws (Image size buffer) = Image size $ runST $ do ...
```

This is the most performant design for CPU-rendering I found, yet it is rather ugly. For a purely functional structure that implements `render`, the obvious answer would be to use a map to represent the Image and a list of `(Position, Pixel)` pairs to represent the sprite. Something like:

```
-- 1D for simplicity
type Position = Int

-- An image is a map from positions to colors
type Image    = Map Position Pixel

-- A sprite is, too, a map from positions to colors
type Sprite   = [(Position, Pixel)]

-- Rendering is just inserting each pixel in sequence
-- (Not tested.)
render :: [Sprite] -> Image -> Image
render sprites image = foldr renderSprite image sprites
    where renderSprite sprite image = foldr (uncurry insert) image sprites
```

Which is `O(P * log(N))` (P = pixels to render, N = size of the image). It might look that the `log(N)` is unescapable, but if you see it carefully, `render` is traveling the same paths through `Image` several times (i.e., if you insert at position 0, then at position 1, you are running all way down to a leaf, then all way up, then all way down to the neighbor leaf...). That looks like the exact same pattern for which `zippers`, for instance, can improve the asymptotics, which leads me to suspect `render` can be improved. **Is there any purely functional data structure that allows implementing `render` better than `O(P*log N)`?**

Note: by "purely functional", I specifically mean a structure that uses nothing but Haskell's algebraic datatypes alone, i.e., without native primitives such as `Int` and `Array` (even though those are technically served as pure data structures nether less).

Comment: How about `Array` or `UArray`?

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but I'd like to ask anyway. In your first approach, Sprite is equivalent to a list of calls to `Position -> Pixel -> ST s ()`. Couldn't it be changed to `[(Position, Pixel)]` to make it nicer while keeping the same performance?

Comment: As far as my skills go, no. The issue is that `Position -> Pixel -> ST ()` always use constant space. For that to work with lists, you have to always count every list will be fused and compiled to a constant space loop. Maybe it was just me, but I couldn't get it to perform the same even with simple rendering patterns...

Comment: Can you give a complete example of how you want to use your Sprites? Usually when I think of sprites I think of images which are smaller than the image they are rendered onto and they are also repositionable. But I can't see how you would do that with your ST version.

Comment: How not? For example, this `Sprite` renders just 2 pixels at positions `6`, `7`: `twoPixels :: Sprite; twoPixels set = set 6 black >> set 7 red`. The pure version would be `twoPixels = [(6, black), (7, red)]`.

Comment: I think with your current definition of `Sprite`, you can't really optimize in the way that you need due to the fact that `render` has no knowledge about what pixels `Sprite` is going to touch. Maybe you could change `Sprite` to also include a list of pixel ranges that it will touch? That might be a shorter list than the one suggested by @madjar in a lot of cases. Using this information, you could maybe come up with an algorithm similar to linear merging to process the union of the sprite ranges, and then "insert" those into your image using an O(P + min{log n, w}) process

Comment: Those on the OP are just examples, though. I'm looking for any datatype/function that implements fast rendering of many sprites, it doesn't have to use my definition of `Sprite` at all.

Comment: Probably something like vty [Image](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vty-5.4.0/docs/src/Graphics-Vty-Image-Internal.html#Image)? It uses chars instead of pixels, but the idea is similar.  [Here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vty-5.4.0/docs/src/Graphics-Vty-PictureToSpans.html#displayOpsForImage) is how it is rendered.

Comment: `HashMap` from `unordered-containers` or `Vector` from `persistent-vector` practically reduces the `log N` factor to constant. But it's still more costly than mutable vectors.

Comment: But it depends on the primitive `Array`.

Comment: `Map` is typically very slow. What happens if you swap in `IntMap`? It won't be nearly as fast as unboxed vectors, but it's certainly a better purely functional baseline.

Comment: @Viclib I think the question is a bit incomplete unless you talk about what reads you want to do from an `Image` (at the moment it is write-only).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the positions in a sprite can be arbitrary (e.g. `[(0,x),(7,y),(5000,z)]`) it seems pretty clear that you can't hope to do better than O(P log N) if you are only allowed to use data structures of bounded branching factor.

If the positions in a sprite are contiguous then you could use a [`Seq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Sequence.html) (fingertree) which supports logarithmic slicing and concatenation to implement `render` in O(log N) time. If your sprite consists of k disjoint contiguous sequences then you can repeat this k times for O(k log N) `render`.

However, I don't think the extension to two dimensions is as easy as you make it sound unless you are willing to give up an extra factor of O(side length of sprite in one dimension). Perhaps there is some kind of finger-k-d tree that avoids this extra factor.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [discrimination](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/discrimination) package to build your `Map` in O(n+p) time:

```
render sprites image
    = flip union image
    . toMapWith (\new old -> new)
    . concat
    $ sprites
```

Comment: I think this is using Array or similar behind the scenes.

Comment: @ReidBarton Indeed, and it can be done with `Array` "in front of the scenes", too, if preferred, with the same asymptotics: just use `(//)` instead of `union` and `toMapWith`.